# Why the initial value p0 you assigned will largely affect the fitting result

Tags: python, curve-fitting

When I assign different initial values to P0, the fitting varies two orders of magnitude. The question is, how could I find the right one as the purpose of the fitting is the search the right parameters.

I got 2 variables and two unknown parameters to be found by a suitable method.

```py
p0 = [0.5,0.3] #initial value
c,cov = curve_fit(titrition,(xp,xd),y,p0)
yp = titrition ((xp,xd),c[0],c[1])
```

Comment: The non-linear fitters work similarly to walking down a rough mountainside in the fog: you can only see near your feet, so you take a few steps and then look near your feet again to change direction, always moving down. You can get stuck in a low spot by doing this, because the fog will not allow you to see far away. Similarly, the non-linear fitters iteratively try to find the change in parameters that reduce fitting error, and then move in that direction. if the error surface is rough, the algorithm can get stuck in a low spot. This is why good starting parameters are required.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't so much a coding question, but a very specific numerics question. `curve_fit` is simply trying to minimize a cost function to fit your function to the data the best it can. I don't know what the function `titration` looks like, but I suspect that optimizing it is non-convex. In other words, `curve_fit` is probably finding a different optimum value depending on the initial guess you supply. This is where you must use some sort of physical intuition to supply a best guess for what the initial conditions should be.

Comment: I personally use the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to generate initial parameter estimates for curve fitting, this generally works so well that no intuition is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help that dispelled my confusion. I will go through differential evolution genetic algorithm for more details.

Comment: I can provide an graphical Python example curve fitter using the scipy module for Differential Evolution to determine initial parameter estimates if that might be useful.

Comment: DE is really powerful but can be very slow. If you are not aiming at automated fitting the best thing is to have a close look at the data and *guess* initial conditions.